# Better way to organize read/write actions in my project

Tags: java, design-patterns

My code contains the following read/write methods to write data to database

**Read methods like**

1. public byte[]readFile(arg1)
2. public byte[] readFile(arg1, arg2)
3. public InputStream readFile(arg1, arg2)
4. public MyStream readFile(arg1, arg2)
5. public byte[] readFile(arg1, arg2, arg3)

**Write methods like**

1. public String[] writeFile(arg1)
2. public String[] writeFile(arg1, arg2)
3. public MyStream writeFile(arg1, arg2) -> file is written from this outputted stream
4. public String[] writeFile(arg1, arg2, arg3)

Various classed access these methods for read and write purpose. Kindly provide me a better way to organize this in a better way.

I would like to have a centralized part where all my read/write would happen.

Someone please help me to choosing an appropriate pattern to organize this well.

Comment: Are your methods synchronized inside?

Comment: No  Coderino Javarino they aren't

Comment: The classes which invoke these methods follow singleton pattern. So, I think they need not be synchronized. Am I clear?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
interface DatabaseServices {
  ... listing all the methods that you want to "combine"

class  DatabaseServicesImpl implements DatabaseServices {
  ... implementing all those methods

enum DatabaseServicesProvider implements DatabaseServices {
  INSTANCE;
  private final DatabaseServices impl = new DatabaseServicesImpl(...
  ... forwarding all service calls to the impl object
```

The above has the advantage that it is "fully" unit-testable (if you just create an enum and put methods on it; you break your ability to test clients that are using the enum).

From there, you go into your existing source code, and throw away all your methods that currently access your data base; replacing them with calls like

```
DatabaseServices services = DatabaseServicesProvider.INSTANCE;
...
services.whatever()
```

Where: the "enum part" is somehow optional. But very often you find that you want such DB related services to be a central authority thing (in other words: a singleton). And enums simply provide a nice, clean solution  to that "global" aspect. If you don't need a central instance (which would  be actually a better thing anyway), just forget about that part.

Comment: Jägermeister I am not clear with the enum part of the code. I would be a very much helpful if you could explain me a bit more please..

Comment: I have a small doubt.. Please clarify me the following so that I could mark your answer as accepted.. What is the advantage of using enum over class in the above example? To acess this enum methods we have to go like `enumName.INSTANCE.methodName()` whereas if we use class in the above example we can access the methods like `classObj.methodName()`... which one is efficient `class` or `enum` and why?

Comment: You really don't care about **efficiency** here **at all**. This is all about "readability" and design aspects. If there are differences at all, they would be in the nanosecond range. You shouldn't waste a second thinking about performance here.