# Which is the appropriate design pattern(singleton/factory pattern) in the following scenario?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, factory

I have read/write actions in my project something similar in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225440/better-way-to-organize-read-write-actions-in-my-project)

The suggested pattern in the answer was `Singleton Pattern` which is implemented with enum. But I have come across my code where we are following

1. Interface containing read/write methods says ClassA
2. Implementation of the interface methods ClassAImpl
3. Factory class contains the code as follows

   ```
     public class ClassAFactory { 

          public static ClassAFactory getInstance() throws Exception {

                return new ClassAImpl();
            }
       }
   ```

   I have the following doubts

> 1. Which is the apt design pattern to organize the code here in this scenario?
> 2. What is the advantage of reusing the same instance again and again, rather than creating a new instance?

PS: The nature of application is a web application. I am trying to have a centralized part/module which does all my read/write operations in database.

Someone please help me to know about this.

Comment: We need to know a little bit more details about the nature of your application. In the example you have posted a singleton is used in relation to reading and writing to a file. It makes sense to have it as singleton because it is easier to synchronize the access to the file and make sure that there are no parallel writes for example. In the example link it does not make sense to have a Factory. But we need to know more about your specific case. What is the problem that your code is trying to solve.

Comment: One question when you say "read/write actions" are we talking about a file read/write ?  If it is a file read write a Factory that is returning a Non Singleton object is not good choice

Comment: Imagine you have two threads trying to write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Added a bit more details to the questions with nature of the application and type of read/write. Please make a look into it and help me with this.

Comment: Did that answer the question?

Comment: I couldn't get through @AlexanderPetrov..

Comment: Ok what is not understandable ? Basically what the article is stating is that there are two main patterns in Spring framework that are in use these are : Repository or/and DAO. And mostly both are declared as Singletons. This is what the article is saying. What is it that you dont understand ask questions.

Comment: Initially I was not sure about what you were asking about @AlexanderPetrov Petrov. Going through the  article.. I'll post the things which are not clear to me soon..

Answer (score 0):

The main reasoning is that having a Singleton it will be easier to synchronize the READ , WRITE operations if needed. This is n case you have a write operations to a non thread safe resources like Files from the file system f.ex. It does not make sense to create a new object overtime and risk potentially multiple threads attempting to write over a non thread safe resource.

In terms of advantages to using a factory that creates a class again and again. I really dont see any advantages.

**Update based on your last edit.** You can use a Repository pattern or DAO and they can be singleton or not. Please read the following post.  I believe it is what you need:

[Spring @Repository best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039901/spring-repository-best-practices)

And one small clarification. It says Spring, but in reality these are principles that can be applied to any situation. So you dont really need Spring in order to apply the topics that are discussed in this post.

Please let me know if this works for you.

**As you can see from the article the Singleton is quite a common way to go in combination with DAO/Repository.**

Comment: The answer which you have posted is really useful.. Please clarify me the following.. 1. I think DAO - the data access object is the result returning after db operation and Repository is nothing but the implementation layer which performs read/write actions over database am i correct? Or am I missing something.. Kindly help me to know better..

Comment: Also, is the present example `interface` followed by `implementation` (the repository) of read/write db methods - is this a repository pattern? I'm lost somewhere..